# Is there a way for me to get the previous 3 months of data, but for every row? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I want to create a table that has two columns, date and count.
Date is basically just date since we started accepting payment until today (let's say 2021-09-01 to today).
Count represents the # of active merchants (i.e. anyone that has processed ANY transaction in the past 3 months)
I understand that in order to get the last 3 months of data from today, I need to do

```
created between date_add ('month', -3, current_date) and current_date
```

Is there a way that I can do that for every single row, so instead of using current_date, I can use the date that is in the date column?

Comment: This will be materially different between RDBMS' - please tag the one you're using. [tag:sql] is way too generic.

Comment: Sample data / expected would help too.  I'm not sure if you're after 1 row per date looking back 3 months or 1 record showing merchant count for the date defined.

Comment: @xQbert 1 row per date looking back 3 months is exactly how I want it! Sorry I am very new to this and I am not sure how to word it properly

Comment: Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table;` and post it into your question? Post along with some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Adding a `count` column has no sense presuming already a transaction table exists, and considering a good DB design which should obey the normalisation rules for an OLTP structure. You can create a SQL view containing COUNT aggregation in order to see that value if the DBMS is MySQL(I don't know how the method works for Presto).